# openweathermap api key is not working with signed apk

Tags: android

I have a open weather map api key, it working well with debug apk, but when i use it with signed apk, my app crashes.

In there website ,there is no any restriction that you can not use it with production.
so why it's happening don't know?

```
weatherDesc.setText(getString(R.string.weather_conditions) + " : " + "Loading...");
                    currTemp.setText(getString(R.string.current_temperature) + " : " + "Loading...");

                    OpenWeatherMapHelper helper = new OpenWeatherMapHelper("api_key");
                    helper.setUnits(Units.METRIC);
                    helper.getCurrentWeatherByGeoCoordinates(latti, longi, new CurrentWeatherCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(CurrentWeather currentWeather) {
                            weatherDesc.setText(getString(R.string.weather_conditions) + " : " + currentWeather.getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                            currTemp.setText(getString(R.string.current_temperature) + " : " + currentWeather.getMain().getTemp() + "°C");

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                            weatherDesc.setText(getString(R.string.weather_conditions) + " : " + " N/A");
                            currTemp.setText(getString(R.string.current_temperature) + " : " + " N/A");

                            MDToast mdToast = MDToast.makeText(DisplayAcitvity.this, "There is some problem ! please try again" + throwable.toString(), MDToast.LENGTH_SHORT, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR);
                            mdToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 400);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    weatherDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.weather_conditions) + " : " + "<font color=red>" + "connect to internet" + "</font>"));
                    currTemp.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.current_temperature) + " : " + "<font color=red>" + "connect to internet" + "</font>"));
                }
```

Comment: If you have unused packages or libraries, then this might result in error when you are trying to build signed apk. So beaware of that. I had similar problem. Trying removing the unused resources.

Comment: is there any shortcut to remove unused classes and resources

Comment: Right click on your app. `refractor -> remove unused resources`

Comment: Yes i did, but it not helps

Comment: then you have to manually look for the unused resources. Post your `logerror` :)

Comment: facing the same, could you please clearly tell how you solved this issue

Comment: @DineshG please see the issue below , if are doing same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry to bother, i got the answer. Actually i was using the third party library to get the value of the temperature and condition with passing geocordinates to it.
now using direct api call to openweathermap with passing zip code in params.
now it solve.
https://openweathermap.org/current